# VBA to highlight cells with different values on same row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm have issues to set the range properly on the variables.

I need that the inputted column name be used as the range to the bottom of the table.
So if the column header is 'Name' in column D and the table extends until row 200, I would lake that the range be set as D2:D200.

When running the Macros step by step, it does seem be able to Set the colum1 or column2 range at all. Any clue what is off here?

```
Sub CompareColumns()

    Dim i           As Integer
    Dim lastRow     As Long
    Dim column1     As Range 'First Column
    Dim column2     As Range 'Second Column
    Dim header1     As String
    Dim header2     As String

    
    'Set worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    'Prompt the user for column inputs
    header1 = Application.InputBox("Enter First Column Header:")
    header2 = Application.InputBox("Enter Second Column Header:")
    
        Set column1 = ws.Rows(1).Find(header1, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not column1 Is Nothing Then
            Set column1 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, column1.Column), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, column1.Column).End(xlUp))
        Else
            MsgBox "Column Header " & header1 & " Not Found!", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If


        Set column2 = ws.Rows(1).Find(header2, LookIn:=xlValues) 'Find other header
        If Not column2 Is Nothing Then
            Set column2 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, column2.Column), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, column2.Column).End(xlUp))
        Else
            MsgBox "Column Header not found"
            Exit Sub
        End If

    'check if both columns have same number of rows
    If column1.Rows.Count <> column2.Rows.Count Then
       MsgBox "Columns do not have same number of rows"
       Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Comparing the Two Columns
    For i = 1 To column1.Rows.Count
        If column1.Cells(i, 1) <> column2.Cells(i, 1) Then 'If Values aren't equal
            column1.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Change First cell's color to red
            column2.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Change Second cell's color to red
        End If
    Next i

    ' Inform
    MsgBox "Operation completed.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Adding `Debug.Print column1.Address, column2.Address` before Comparing the Two Columns to validate the column range.

Comment: If your table is an Excel table, let us know. If the table (range) starts in `A1`, you could use `CurrentRegion` to reference the whole range. This will allow you to have data to the right or to the bottom of your table, of course, with an empty row and column in between. If it's not in `A1` it gets a bit trickier. Let's say `Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion`. Then you could do `Dim Col1: Col1 = Application.Match(header1, rg.Rows(1), 0): If IsNumeric(Col1) Then: Set column1 = rg.Columns(Col1).Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1): Else: MsgBox "...": Exit Sub: EndIf`.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does seem be able to Set the colum1 or column2 range at all"?  Are the headers really on the first row of the active sheet? If so, is `column1` `Nothing`? `Find` had more parameters. Is the header exactly as you write in `InputBox`? I mean, does the heder **contain** that value or it is the whole value? Is it case sensitive?

Comment: Hey @VBasic2008 
Yes I work in Excel Tables most of the time.
And yes my tables start in A1

Where would the CurrentRegion be used?
Would that be on the line where I set the Column 1 and 2 ?

Comment: @FaneDuru

Yes the headers are on the first row of the active sheet.
What I meant is when I read the Locals window while running the VBA step by step, I see that for value there is written "noting" for the variable column1 and column2.

While for the variable header1 and header2, there is correctly the name I imputed in the message box.

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome
Thank you for the suggestion.

So this prints 
$B$2:$B$3     $B$2:$B$3
$B$2:$B$3     $B$2:$B$3

Very strange because my data is in A1:B3 and B1:B3
No idea why A is being ignored.

Comment: Then, it is possible to have a typo in the code you work on it. Please, check if `Set column1 = ws.Rows(1).Find(header1, LookIn:=xlValues)` you show does not look as `Set column1 = ws.Rows(1).Find(header2, LookIn:=xlValues)`. I mean, using the same `header2` for both columns to be found... Then, how both columns are not set "at all"? Do you receive the  `"Column Header not found"` messages?

Comment: Hello @FaneDuru

I found what the issue was.
The .Find function was not able to find the column correctly.
I refined the .Find parameters the following way

`Set column1 = ws.Rows(1).Find(header1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) ' Find header`

By adding the LookIn, LookAt, the MatchCase and the SearchFormat it its able to find the columns.

It now works good.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code
*Still some improvements can be done of course, including the message box at the end which always show even if cells were colored.

```
Sub CompareColumns()

    Dim ws          As Worksheet
    Dim i           As Integer
    Dim lastRow     As Long
    Dim column1     As Range 'First Column
    Dim column2     As Range 'Second Column
    Dim header1     As String
    Dim header2     As String

    
    'Set worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    'Prompt the user for column inputs
    header1 = Application.InputBox("Enter First Column Header:")
    header2 = Application.InputBox("Enter Second Column Header:")
    
        Set column1 = ws.Rows(1).Find(header1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) ' Find header
        If Not column1 Is Nothing Then
            Set column1 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, column1.Column), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, column1.Column).End(xlUp))
        Else
            MsgBox "Column Header " & header1 & " Not Found!", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If


        Set column2 = ws.Rows(1).Find(header2, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'Find other header
        If Not column2 Is Nothing Then
            Set column2 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, column2.Column), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, column2.Column).End(xlUp))
        Else
            MsgBox "Column Header not found"
            Exit Sub
        End If

    ' Debug to validate the column range
    Debug.Print column1.Address, column2.Address
    

    'check if both columns have same number of rows
    If column1.Rows.Count <> column2.Rows.Count Then
       MsgBox "Columns do not have same number of rows"
       Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Comparing the Two Columns
    For i = 1 To column1.Rows.Count
        If column1.Cells(i, 1) <> column2.Cells(i, 1) Then 'If Values aren't equal
            column1.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Change First cell's color to red
            column2.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Change Second cell's color to red
        End If
    Next i

    ' Inform
    MsgBox "Operation completed.", vbInformation
End Sub
```